# Fortran Modules - Variable declarations conflict in module with main program

Tags: module, fortran, declaration, structured-programming

I have a FORTRAN 95 code where, in the main program, these variables are declared:

```
integer :: i
real(8) :: dx                               
real(8), allocatable :: X(:), Y(:), Z(:)
```

The following function uses these values at some point during the program:

```
function Funcion_ceros(var_4)           
        implicit none
        real(8), intent(in) :: var_4(2)
            real(8) :: Funcion_ceros(2)
            Funcion_ceros(1) = var_4(1) - Y(i) - dx*var_4(2)
            Funcion_ceros(2) = var_4(2) - Z(i) - dx*F(X(i + 1), var_4(1), var_4(2))
end function Funcion_ceros
```

If I include this function in the contains section of the main program, there is no compiling issue. However, when separating it into a module, it loses access to these variables. I attempt to specify the same variabes written above in the module aswell, and get the following error:

```
Symbol 'i' at (1) conflicts with symbol from  module 'Module_Name', use associated at (2).
```

How do I separate this function into a module, allowing at the same time its access to the variables it uses from the main program?

Answer (score 2):

You can put the variables into the module as well, then the `use` statement makes them available to the main program as well.

```
module scope_mod
    implicit none
    character(len=4) :: a = "mod "
    character(len=4) :: b = "mod "
    character(len=4) :: c = "mod "
contains
    subroutine sub()
        implicit none
        character(len=4) :: b
        a = "sub "
        b = "sub "
        write(*, *) "in sub: A from ", a, ", B from ", b, ", C from ", c
    end subroutine sub
end module scope_mod

program scope_test
    use scope_mod
    implicit none
    a = "main"
    write(*, *) "in main: A from ", a, ", B from ", b, ", C from ", c
    call sub()
    write(*, *) "after sub: A from ", a, ", B from ", b, ", C from ", c
end program scope_test
```

Output:

```
 in main: A from main, B from mod , C from mod 
 in sub: A from sub , B from sub , C from mod 
 after sub: A from sub , B from mod , C from mod
```

**Update:** I noticed that you said you put the variables in the module 'as well' -- If you have them in the module, they will be made available to the main program by the `use` statement. If you then declare another variable with the same name, it will conflict. Declare the variables *only* in the module, and they will be available to both.